# Does django manage.py migrate command creates database/schema if not exists?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an existing django project and need to create an instance of it in a new environment with new database. I have the database connection configured in the settings file. The schema does not exist. If I run the `manage.py migrate` command, does it also create the schema? It looks like it assumes the schema already exists because I am getting an error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'my_db'")`. Just wondering if I have to create the database first or if some django command is available to create it if it does not exists.

I can create the schema manually via sql script if it's not doable via python django command.

Comment: The database has to exists, the tables will be created.

Comment: try `makemigrations` instead of `migrate`

Comment: @hansTheFranz the makemigrations command will only create the python files containing the migrations, but not do anything in the database itself.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments to your question, the missing database is the problem, not the schema. You have to create the database first, which might involve setting the user permissions for the new database. After that, the `manage.py migrate` command will work just fine and create the schema for you.